# How to distinguish <div> from <?php ?> using php regex?

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

How to distinguish `<div>` from `<?php ?>` using php regex ?
`div` is just an example. I need in `<smth> <?php code ?> </smth>`  distinguish between `smth` and `?php code ?`, where smth and code may be any characters combination.

I would like to get content of `<div>`, but not of `<?php ? >`, and sometimes vise versus

```
$regex1 = '#<(?<!\?)(.*?)>#' ;  // result : div , ?php ? , /div  .
```

I do not need php in this case.

```
$regex1 = '#<(?<!\??)(.*?)>#' ;  //Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 8
```

The second question would be how to retrieve  `inside <?php ?>` inside `<div>` and similar html markup

```
$htmlStr = " before <div> inside <?php ?> </div> after ";
        $regex1 = '#(.*)'  //before 
                . '<(?!\?)' // < not followed by ?
                . '(.*)' // div
                . '((?<!\?)>)'// > not preceeded by ?
                . '(.*)' // Retrieves only 'inside', instead of 'inside  <?php ? >'
                . '</' //  </
                . '.*'  // div
                . '((?<!\?)>)'   // > not preceeeded by ?
                . '(.*)#'; // after
```

I also have tried non-greedy expression :

```
$regex1 = '#(.*)'  //before 
        . '<(?!\?)' // < not followed by ?
        . '(.*)' // div
        . '((?<!\?)>)'// > not preceeded by ?
        . '(.*?)' // // non-greedy expression fetch only 'inside', but i need 'inside  <?php ? >'
        . '</' //  </
        . '.*'  // div
        . '((?<!\?)>)'   // > not preceeeded by ?
        . '(.*)#'; // after
```

Final adjustment. DOM also does not rerieve value if it contains  . The code below   line`foreach ($els as $el) { echo '<br><br>element value ='. $el->nodeValue; }` echoes  `inside` instead of `inside <?php ?>`

```
$htmlStr = " before <div> inside <?php ?> </div> after ";      
$regex1 = '#(.*)<([a-zA-Z]+)>'// > not preceeded by ?  [a-zA-Z]
        . '(.*)' // greedy expression fetch only 'inside', but i need 'inside  <?php ? >'  (?=<\/)' 
        . '</' //  </
        . '[a-zA-Z]+'  // div
        . '(?<!\?)>'   // > not preceeeded by ?
        . '(.*)#'; // after  */
preg_match_all($regex1, $htmlStr, $attrArr1, 0); //input
$attrArr1 = array_filter($attrArr1);
print_r('<br><br> 619 htmlStr=' . $htmlStr. ',   attrArr1 = <pre>'); print_r($attrArr1); 

$dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0'); // name, value 
$dom->loadHTML($htmlStr); 
$ansArr['elType'] = $attrArr1[2][0];
//$els = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*'); // To be done 
$els = $dom->getElementsByTagName($ansArr['elType'] );
foreach ($els as $el) { echo '<br><br>element value ='. $el->nodeValue; } //gives value 'inside'
print_r('<br><br>620 elType='.$ansArr['elType'].',   els='); print_r($els);
```

Comment: Use a parser instead. The xpath query will be sth. like `$xpath->query("//div");`.

Comment: [Here be dragons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/354577). While it may be possible to handle specific narrow use cases with regular expressions in general it is **_literally not possible_** to parse HTML with regex. It's almost always better to use a proper XML / HTML parser like [`DOMDocument`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or an XML query language like [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) as suggested by Jan.

Answer (score 1):

> answer to your first question :

***( 'get content of <­smth> but not of <­?php ?>' )***  [*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/iIYvSS/4)

```
input  >> <smth id="test">Hello World!</smth><?php echo "Hello World!"?>
regex  >> (?<=<smth\s)(.*?)(?=>)
output >> id="test"
```

> answer to your second question :

***('retrieve inside <­?php ?>')***  [*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/iIYvSS/2)

```
input  >> <smth id="test">Hello World!</smth><?php echo "Hello World!"?>
regex  >> (?<=<\?php\s)(.*?)(?=\?>)
output >> echo "Hello World!"
```

***('retrieve inside <­smth> and similar html markup')***  [*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/iIYvSS/5)

```
input  >> <smth id="test">Hello World!</smth><?php echo "Hello World!"?>
regex  >> (?<=<smth[\s]id="test">).*?(?=<\/smth>)  // not efficient
output >> Hello World!
```

Hope these helps!

Comment: I am sorry, `div` is just an example. I need <smth> <?php ?> </smth>

Comment: @olga check updated answer. now it should work for `<smth>`

Comment: i mean i do not know in advance if it will be `smth` of `div` or `span` or `input`, etc... `smth` shall not be part of regex. Thank you for answer. It has a good point. Sorry, for not clear enought question.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the regex works, just it does not print the `<?php ?>`, because it is not a string in webrowser content. Nevertheless, if you add some text after ,you will get everything. Also if you write result to file, you will find not only word `inside`, but also `inside <?php ?> smth`

```
   //$regex2 ='#(.*)<([a-zA-Z]+)(.*?)(?<!\?)>(.*)</[a-zA-Z]+(?<!\?)>(.*)#'; for textarea, also div/span/p/a and other elements having closing tags.

//$regex3 ='#(.*)<([a-zA-Z]+)(.*?)/>(.*)#'; //for input

// Textarea
$htmlStr2 = " before <textarea name='<?php  ?>' > inside '<?php ? >' smth. </textarea> after ";   
//$regex2 ='#(.*)<([a-zA-Z]+)(.*?)(?<!\?)>(.*)</[a-zA-Z]+(?<!\?)>(.*)#'; for textarea
$regex2 = '#(.*)<([a-zA-Z]+)' // > not preceeded by ?  textarea[a-zA-Z]+
        . '(.*?)' //  attributes (.*?)
        . '(?<!\?)>'// > not preceeded by ?  
        . '(.*)' // fetch <?php ? >
        . '</' //  </
        . '[a-zA-Z]+'  // div
        . '(?<!\?)>'   // > not preceeeded by ?
        . '(.*)#'; // after  
preg_match_all($regex2, $htmlStr2, $attrArr, 0); //input
$attrArr = array_filter($attrArr); //array_filter removes empty values
print_r('<br><br> 619 htmlStr=' . $htmlStr. ',   attrArr1 = <pre>'); print_r($attrArr); 
$resStr =  print_r($attrArr, true); 
print_r('<br><br> resStr='.$resStr);
file_put_contents('C:\\Users\\gintare\\Documents\\reg2.txt', $resStr);
$before = $attrArr1[1][0]; // before
$tagType = $attrArr1[2][0]; //input
$tagAttrStr = $attrArr1[3][0]; //name='<?php  ? >'
$inside = $attrArr1[4][0]; //inside '<?php ? >' smth.
$afer = $attrArr1[5][0]; //after

//Input  
$htmlStr3 = " before <input class='inp' > after '<?php ? >' smth. ";  
//$regex3 ='#(.*)<([a-zA-Z]+)(.*?)/>(.*)#'; //for input
$regex3 = '#(.*)<([a-zA-Z]+)' // > not preceeded by ?  input[a-zA-Z]+
        . '(.*?)' //  attributes (.*?)
        . '/>'//
        . '(.*)'; // after
preg_match_all($regex3, $htmlStr3, $attrArr, 0); //input
$attrArr = array_filter($attrArr); //array_filter removes empty values
print_r('<br><br> 619 htmlStr=' . $htmlStr. ',   attrArr1 = <pre>'); print_r($attrArr); 
$resStr =  print_r($attrArr, true); 
print_r('<br><br> resStr='.$resStr);
file_put_contents('C:\\Users\\gintare\\Documents\\reg3.txt', $resStr);
$before = $attrArr1[1][0]; // before
$tagType = $attrArr1[2][0]; //input
$tagAttrStr = $attrArr1[3][0]; //name='<?php  ? >'
$after = $attrArr1[4][0]; //after
```